# Space version of a monopoly like game?

Tags: identify-this-game

Trying to find a boardgame from my childhood.  it was basically Monopoly in space.

- all the pieces were little rockets
- the board was a map of our solar system
- each moon around the planets had deed cards
- there were these little metal objects that were fuel depots
- you could put the fuel depots on the moons you bought
- there was also a fuel tracker and if you ran out of fuel you lost the game

anyone remember the name of this game? would have come out probably mid-1980's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Googling "space monopoly" brings up [Solarquest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solarquest).

Comment: Yep, this looks like the game!  thank you sir.  Also didn't know they recently did a reprint.  just ordered a copy from amazon! sweet